# Python executing sendmail but not sending email

Tags: python, email, sendmail

I have checked Stackoverflow and found similar questions but none seem to answer my specific issue. I'm using Python 2.6.

The following function was used to successfully send a plain text email with an attachment via sendmail:

```
def sndmsg(u,A,a):
    """
    + sends email(s) with plain text and attachment

    u = str - company url
    A = str - manager's name
    a = list of email addresses to send to
    """
    u=u.replace('/','')
    file = open('message.txt','rb')
    txt=file.read()
    file.close()
    for t in a:
        out = MIMEMultipart()
        out['Subject'] = 'Free Report'
        out['From'] = 'admin@example.com'
        out['To'] = t.strip()
        out['Date'] = date()

        pt1 = MIMEText(txt.format(A,u))
        out.attach(pt1)

        att = MIMEApplication(open('/path/'+u+'.xls',"rb").read())
        att.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=u+'.xls')
        out.attach(att)

        p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
        p.communicate(out.as_string())
```

It was then modified to include html formatted text (below). The code executes fine and moves onto the next function without errors but this time I receive no email in any of my inboxes or spam folders.

```
def sndmsg(u,A,a):
    """
    + sends email(s) with html text, plain text and attachment

    u = str - company url
    A = str - manager's name
    a = list of email addresses to send to

    H[0] = str - html table
    """
    u=u.replace('/','')
    file = open('message.txt','rb')
    txt=file.read()
    file.close()
    file = open('message.html','rb')
    htm=file.read()
    file.close()
    for t in a:
        out = MIMEMultipart()
        out['Subject'] = 'Free Report'
        out['From'] = 'admin@example.com'
        out['To'] = t.strip()
        out['Date'] = date()

        inn = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        pt1 = MIMEText(txt.format(A,u))
        pt2 = MIMEText(htm.format(A,u,H[0]), 'html')
        inn.attach(pt1)
        inn.attach(pt2)
        out.attach(inn)

        att = MIMEApplication(open('/path/'+u+'.xls',"rb").read())
        att.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=u+'.xls')
        out.attach(att)

        p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
        p.communicate(out.as_string())
```

My primary question is whether it is a coding problem or a `Sendmail` problem.

I tried using the second function independently and opened the html message separately in my browser and it looks great but the email is still not sent.

I don't have root access to `SSH` into the server and check `/var/log/mail`. I've asked the server administrator but not got any help.

If it's a coding error what would need to be fixed or improved?

Thanks for your patience with my ignorance and for your kind assistance.

Comment: Well, for one thing, `H` is undefined.

Comment: thanks for the comment. yes, H is a global var containing a list of str that are called in other functions to produce html tables, one of which H[0] is inserted into this template email.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `-i` to sendmail's coammand line options

   `p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-i"], stdin=PIPE)`
2. Explicitely close pipe created by Popen

   `rc = p.close()
   if rc is not None and rc >> 8:
       print "There were some errors"`
3. If it fails to fix then add `-v` (verbose/debug) option to sendmail's command line options and execute your sctipt in terminal to see its stderr output.

---

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, thank you for the documentation. It really helps to know just where to look. I should have really looked there first but I wasn't sure what to look for.  Now I know.  Thank you again.  :)